# Need to read a tar.gz file inside a jar as file

Tags: java

I am trying to access the file inside a jar but getting exception

```
String tarFilePath = "data/";
```

My code looks like below 
I am trying in couple of ways one by reading as stream and trying to access from stream

```
InputStream in1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream(tarFilePath + "test_data.tar.gz");
                TarArchiveInputStream tarArchiveInputStream= new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(in1));

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.<init>(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:128)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.<init>(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:100)
    at com.motive.systemtest.stepsdef.HttpReceiverSteps.given_method(HttpReceiverSteps.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

2nd way

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(tarFilePath + tarFileName).getFile());

 java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/username/Projects/systemtest/target/systemtest-1.0.0-fat-tests.jar!/data/test_data.tar.gz (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.writeTo(FileEntity.java:94)
        at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:94)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:266)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:216)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at com.motive.systemtest.stepsdef.HttpReceiverSteps.postChunkFileHttpReceiver(HttpReceiverSteps.java:146)
        at com.motive.systemtest.stepsdef.HttpReceiverSteps.given_method(HttpReceiverSteps.java:66)
```

1 st way throws null pointer exception and second throws file not found exception . 
[image]

Is it possible to access resource under a jar as file
Please check and help me on this

Comment: Where's your `tar.gz` located inside your `jar`? Use a zip-editing tool to make sure it's where you expect it to be. In the first solution you tried, what's the value of `tarFilePath` ? The first solution should be the way to go, but the `NullPointerException` you're getting likely means the path you specified is incorrect.

Comment: Added tarfilepath in the above question Please let me know how to specify the path @Aaron

Comment: BTW just to be sure, can you confirm the `jar` you're trying to get the `.tar.gz` from is the one you're running code from, or at least one that is in your classpath? The first method relies on that. If it's not the case, you'll have to read the `jar` as a zip archive from your java code to get your `.tar.gz`, which is burdensome.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt should work, only tarFilePath must start with a slash.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/test_data.tar.gz")
```

begins from the root directory of your jar.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("data/test_data.tar.gz")
```

looks into a subdirectory relative to your class file.